# Django view with list (order and pagination) and Delete-function?

Tags: django

I have a html-template where I list users Django model objects. This page also have a pagination and links to order the objects. Now I'm thinking of putting a delete-button on each object, which deletes it from the list and database without breaking the order or pagination (returning the current queryset without the deleted object).

I've tried with a delete-view with it's own url but I think the best would be to put it all in the same view to be able to return/handle the order_by and pagination. Something like my pagination links that loads a href like:

"mylist/?page={{ results.next_page_number }}&order_by={{ order_by }}"

But with an additional delete-someID-parameter (what's the preferred method?). I'm not sure if this is the clean (and secure?) way to do this? I'm thinking of checking the objects user against the logged in user also.

```
deleteid = get_object_or_404(Mymodel, pk=?) #what to do here?
if deleteid.user == request.user:
    deleteid.delete()
```

I'm thinking right here? I need some guidance to put all this together.

View:

```
def Mylist(request):

    order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', 'somedefault')   
    myobjects_list = Mymodel.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by(order_by)
    paginator = Paginator(myobjects_list, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'results ': results, 'order_by': order_by }
    return render_to_response('mylist.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You are creating a query string and you can get the values in your view by referencing the keys in request.MET['QUERY_STRING'] you can try to use the login_required decorator to make sure the user is logged in. I just wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i didn't want to use the login_required decorator on the whole view so I could use the listing functions without the delete options in other templates What do you think about the solution in the answer below (by radev)? Is that more like something you would do?

Comment: That's how I would have done it. You can apply the id of the object as an id for each item listed and remove it with javascript when the ajax responds.

Comment: Ok. I'm thinking of giving each div (or li) in the list the object-id template tag as the div id-attribute to check which one to remove/hide. But Im not sure how. Should i return the id from the view or how do I do it? Or simply use some remove this-parent type of thing when i get the success?

Comment: If you can send the object id to the view you can return it as a json response. This will give you a very good overview: https://godjango.com/18-basic-ajax/

Comment: I'll check that! Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would do it:

1. Issue an ajax call to a django view to delete the entry on a url like /entery/3/delete ,
2. that view would check validation , execute delete and return a simple success/failure
   flag (maybe in json or so),
3. on the client side, execute -on success- a java script to hide that entry from the current page. (ie. Set style:display to None or delete the HTML element).

That way i get fast response , less network traffic that isn't needed , a better user experience and a heightened security.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool. Thank you, that is a very helpful and interesting solution! I'm gonna try some with this (I'm no good with javascript but maybe i can do it entirely with jquery?)

Comment: entirely with jquery .. Sure !! :-)

Comment: What should i return from the delete-view. I mean the "flag".. A variable, a boolean, the ID? Not sure how to identify the div to hide/remove on the success. Thanks again

Comment: What is meant by flag is anything you agree on that makes meaning... simple as a string that says "OK" or "FAIL:not entery owner", it can be HTML status code .. it can be anything as long as it makes sense to you and your maybe dev team.
You can identify a div element through various type of selectors , based on your html structure. ie. In template , wrap each element in a div with an id="modelname{{ object.pk }}".

Answer (score 1):

in my views.py

```
def ProjectDetail(request,pk):
    context = {}
    template = 'views/projectdetail.html'
    project = ''
    prev = Project.objects.filter(pk__lt=pk).order_by('-pk')[:1]
   next = Project.objects.filter(pk__gt=pk).order_by('pk')[:1]
try:
    print(prev[0].pk)
    print(next[0].pk)
except:
    pass
project = Project.objects.filter(pk=pk)
context['categories'] = ProjectCategory.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(project, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    data = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    data = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
if prev:
    context['prev'] = prev[0].pk
if next:
    context['next'] = next[0].pk
context['data'] = data
return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in my template i have

```
 <div class="row">
      <a {% if next %} href="{% url 'task:project-detail' next %}"    class="btn btn-primary pull-right" {% else %} class="btn btn-primary pull-right disabled" {% endif %}>Next</a>



    <a {% if prev %} href="{% url 'task:project-detail' prev %}" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" {% else %} class="btn btn-primary pull-left disabled" {% endif %} >Previous</a>

    </div>
```